# Cloud9 won't deploy to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloud

Hey I'm in an online boot camp and I need to deploy my app to Heroku and I'm using the Cloud9 IDE but every time I go to the page it says it doesn't exist even though I followed the instructions.
https://github.com/weredre/achievement3

Comment: It looks like you haven't run `heroku create` yet.

Comment: That's the thing I have already

Comment: How about `heroku login`?

Comment: yup the app is made it's just when I open the app it says The page you were looking for doesn't exist.